# Yii 2.0 Restful Web Service Api

Tags: php, rest, yii2

Anyone using the integrated RESTful Web Service in Yii 2.0(beta)?

The instructions in the official [documentation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/rest-quick-start.md) looks simple but it didn't work for me: 
I'm using the basic template, have used the gii module to create a simple *'category'* model extending `ActiveRecord`, then i created the `CategoriesController` extending the `ActiveController`:

```
# Content of the file app\controllers\CategoriesController.php

<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class CategoriesController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Category';
}
```

Now the model `Category` is assigned to the `$modelClass` property which will be needed by the `ActiveController` Class to relate it with the already defined CRUD actions like `index` or `view`:(
see [ActiveController::actions()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rest/ActiveController.php) )

My `UrlManager` configs looks like:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,

            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'categories'],
            ],

        ],
```

Because my webserver's documentRoot and my webapp are in separate folders, my htaccess file under the WEB folder looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /~salem/alpha2/web

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

`PrettyUrls` & `showScriptName` to false are just working fine, but when trying to access to **localhost/~salem/alpha2/web/categories** i'm having the following error:

```
Not Found (#404)
Unable to resolve the request "categories/index".
```

Any one have any idea about what i'm doing wrong??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the same docs linked above: "...When creating a new controller class, a convention in naming the controller class is to use the type name of the resource and use singular form. For example, to serve user information, the controller may be named as UserController..." i desabled the enableStrictParsing, removed Rules, then renamed my controller to CategoryController now! it works!

Comment: I have the same issue. And solve it using your solution. But any idea how to mix URL routes for the regular web request and webs service?

Comment: @Pelang you can keep both if you build your REST API as an independent module. then `/web` will work as always did while you can have a `/api` endpoint for only xml and/or json outputs. [this tutorial By Joachim Werner](https://www.diggin-data.de/dd-cms/blog/post/view/id/1004/name/Creating+a+REST+API+for+Yii2-basic-template) shows how to do it and how to use 2 config files for each of the 2 endpoints. hope it helps.